# Ruby On Rails - Pass parameters from front end to database through controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to pass parameters from front end to back-end API in Ruby on Rails only through controllers? I do not want to use model or views for this.

I am using a Ruby Gem which captures some usage data which needs to be stored into the back end database.

I have created a controller, to which the post parameters are sent, but I get an error saying view is not found.

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template usage_metrics/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json, :js, :html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip, :web_console_v2], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/local/www/cc2/cc_user-frontend/app/views"
  * "/home/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/ckeditor-4.2.2/app/views"
):
```

Comment: can you post your UsageMetrics controller

Comment: Your action needs to output something via `render`, or it's assumed you want to render a view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the request in an appropriate format (i.e. json) and ensure the controller action responds to this. At the moment it's trying to respond with html but not finding a template for this.

For example, in the action, after you've done what you need to do:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: { whatever: is_needed_in_the_response } }
end
```

And you'll get your response that way.

Or if you don't need a response after parsing the params, you can use `render nothing: true`.

N.B. I think the newest versions Rails will respond with nothing / json if there's no template found. Not sure how this affects you.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to return some data as json you can use

```
render json: data
```

but if you only want to return status

```
render json: {}, status: 200
```